# Rewriting the whole URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I know how to use Apache's mod_rewrite in a common way but now I'm trying to use it in a different way which was not a success to this moment. Here's what I wrote:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^([^.]+)\.internal$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.local$1
```

And here's the whole story:

I have added two lines to my `hosts` file like so:

```
127.0.0.1    test.local
127.0.0.1    test.internal
```

I've also added a virtual host for `test.local` in my Apache and created a file so the URL `http://test.local/info.php` prints out PHP's configuration and stuff. Now let's get back to mod_rewrite directives; I was hoping by writing what I wrote at the begging of the post, when I open the URL `http://test.internal/info.php` it will be served by `test.local/info.php` script. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

BTW, I've written the given directives in Apache's main configuration file, not in a virtual host's and I insists on this.

**[UPDATE]**

I've added the following two lines to Apache's configuration file so I can debug the `Rewrite`'s behaviour:

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

I have couple of virtual hosts on this machine which use `Rewrite` and when I visit them, due to these two lines a log file is created in the specified path. But when I visit `http://test.internal/info.php` no log file is created.

**[UPDATE]**

I'm going to clarify my aim maybe I'm doing everything wrong from scratch.

I have numerous VPSs each hosting a different website. And they all reside in a local network and I want to add a frontend to this collection of website so they can be accessed from the Internet. But the thing is that members of this collection are dynamically added or removed so I don't want to modify my DSN and/or reverse proxy server's config file each time something's changed. I can use a wildcard in DNS server to direct all of requests to a specific domain to the frontend (the reverse proxy server) and then it will be up to the frontend to redirect the request to the appropriate VPS using their subdomain (each subdomain is assigned to a VPS logically). To this end I will setup a local DNS mapping some dummy domain names to internal VPS IP's. All that remains is that reverse proxy server should rewrite the request's URL so it matches the dummy domains.

The only part of this solution that I can't grasp is how to tell Apache to map the incoming requests' domain to dummy ones!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Often, if you enable logging of `mod_rewrite` activity via the `RewriteLog` directive these problems become much easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it and update the question if I could discover anything new.

Comment: If you have these rewrite rules in the global configuration then you'll need to put `RewriteOptions Inherit` in any `VirtualHost` directives for them to inherit the rules.

Comment: That's the point, I don't want these rules in any of the virtual hosts. I just want the incoming URL to be rewritten. Much like it happens in mod_proxy but this time the domain part is matched and rewritten. Later I will leave no virtual host on this instance of Apache and take them all away to some other machine. This one will only play a reverse proxy role.

Comment: Are you following the instructions on [Dynamic mass virtual hosts with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/vhosts.html)? If so, did you see [their document on why that's generally a bad idea](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#vhosts) unless necessary (for instance, if you can only edit .htaccess)? Why don't you want to configure virtual hosts on the reverse proxy?

Comment: No I'm not trying to implement massive virtual hosts, instead I'm trying to implement massive reverse proxy rules using `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Sure, but you can do that with virtual hosts, so the question remains. Why don't you want to configure virtual hosts on the reverse proxy instead of using mod_rewrite?

Comment: I read your update. Your situation is a bit different than what I usually face, because I don't have that many web servers and they are relatively static. Still, I don't understand one thing in your plan. You say you are doing this to avoid changing the configuration every time a VPS is added or removed, but with your current approach you would still have to change the RewriteRules, right? Or would your long term plan involve using regular expressions there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to solve my problem, it's called **[mod_proxy_express](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_express.html)** and it's available in Apache 2.4. It's capable of mapping a mass number of domains to their IPs using a database.